# Enviar para o banco uma série de dados acumulados durante o dia, é possível?

Tags: php, sql, desempenho

Me veio uma dúvida, para armazenar dados de eventos e navegações que o usuário realiza no site, seria possível somente enviar para o banco após o termino do dia, as ações que os usuários realizaram durante o dia, ou salvar somente quando ele fechar a guia do site? É possível? E teria alguma vantagem de se fazer isso ao invés de registrando conforme o usuário fosse realizando a ação? A minha dúvida nisso é gerar muito peso no servidor, fazendo requisições a todo momento e com vários usuários logados.

Comment: Em tese se o dado precisa ser armazenado o melhor é gravar logo no banco pois este garante integridade. O volume de "log" seria muito grande ?

Comment: Seria registrado o link, ip e hora, e id do usuario caso logado. Isso a cada mudança na url. Com alguns usuários simultâneos.

Comment: Por que não vai adicionando esses valores a uma variável e a cada X time com o usuário logado você manda esses dados para o banco de dados?

Comment: Então... Pensei mais ou menos nessa lógica, mas queria saber se traria benefícios fazer isso, e de que forma seria melhor fazer esse armazenamento antes de repassar ao banco.

Comment: O problema é o risco de perder em uma queda , precisando logar em tese o melhor seria gravar direto no banco.

Comment: Dessa forma você só estará gerando mais problemas ainda. como você vai garantir que os dados serão salvos?

Comment: Realmente, é algo a se pensar...